# run a remote bash script with arguments with ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, tput

I am unable to run a remote shell script located on "admin" server with arguments.

```
ssh koliwada@admin "~/bin/addautomaps $groupentry $homeentry $ticket"
```

"groupentry" and "homeentry" are as follows

```
user1:*:52940:OWNER-user1
user1       -rw,intr,hard,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 basinas01:/ifs/basinas01/home/&
```

the script is located at ~/bin/addautomaps in admin server.

I see the error,

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

I also see the arguments also are not passed correctly.
I also tried using "ssh -t ..." but that doesnt work.

Comment: Try this:
`ssh koliwada@admin script -c "~/bin/addautomaps $groupentry $homeentry $ticket" /dev/null`

Comment: @anishsane: Can you explain the rationale behind your answer?

Comment: my bad. From `man script`: `The inner shell of script is always interactive`. So the command passed as `-c` is run in an interactive shell.

Comment: Informative! So the reason for the failure is that the bash `env` variables are not properly read then?

Comment: that doesnt work!

       ` tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
        bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
        usage: script [ -a ] [ typescript ]`

Comment: You need to quote the arguments inside the command for the remote shell as well as the entire string for ssh. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36895203/258523) for a similar issue. That should solve the "passed correctly" issue (assuming I understood what you meant there). As to the `tput` issue that's a warning you can probably ignore if you don't care about the colorized/stylized/etc. output that `tput` is likely being used to create.

Comment: @EtanReisner: That worked very well for me!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions in reverse order (or most serious to least serious).

Your problem with the arguments (with spaces) not being passed correctly is that while you are quoting the command string locally you **aren't** quoting them when they are actually run by the remote machine.

That is you are generating a single string with the variables expanded but nothing tells the remote system not to split the expanded values on spaces.

The fix for that is that you need to quote the arguments inside the command for the remote shell as well as the entire string for ssh.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36895203/258523) might help explain some (it is a similar issue).

The `tput` "issue" is likely just a warning that you can probably ignore if you don't care about the colorized/stylized/etc. output that `tput` is likely being used to create. You could also try forcing a value for `$TERM` on the remote side like `ssh ... "export TERM=dumb; ..."` or something like that to silence it.